# Call a package's function without using its package name?

Tags: go

Example:

```
package "main"

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hey there")
}
```

Could be written:

```
package "main"

import blah "fmt"

func main() {
    blah.Println("hey there")
}
```

But is there anyway to import `fmt` to achieve:

```
package "main"

import "fmt" // ???

func main() {
    Println("hey there")
}
```

In C# by contrast, you can do this by using a static import (e.g., `using static System.Console`). Is this possible in Go?

Comment: my bad, thanks for recover.

Comment: np I just learned that 10 minutes ago myself

Comment: I don't agree with the downvotes because I believe this is a valid question; Especially for someone new to Go. Upvoting!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the . (explicit period) import.  The [specification says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations):

> If an explicit period (.) appears instead of a name, all the package's exported identifiers declared in that package's package block will be declared in the importing source file's file block and must be accessed without a qualifier.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    . "fmt"
)

func main() {
    Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

The use of the explicit period is discouraged in the Go community. The dot import makes programs more difficult to read because it's unclear if a name is a package-level identifier in the current package or in an imported package.

Another option is to declare a package-level variable with a reference to the function. Use a [type alias](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Alias_declarations) to reference types.

```
 package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var Println = fmt.Println

type ScanState = fmt.ScanState // type alias


func main() {
    Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Comment: When you say it's discouraged by the Go community, I presume that's because the function call is less explicit?

Comment: @tarrball Yes, that's correct. I updated the answer with an explanation.