# Is there a way to avoid writing submodules names

Tags: go

If I've the below:

```golang
|--main.go
|--models
     |-- defenitions.go
```

And in `definistions.go` I've the below:

```
package models
type Person struct {
     name  string
     age   uint
}
```

If I want to call `Person` at `main.go` I've to use this;

```golang
package main
import "models"

func main(){
     p := models.Person{name: "Karam", age: 5}
}
```

Is there a way to avoid mentioning `models.Person{...}` and be able to use only `Person{...}`

Comment: One remark: These are neither modules nor submodules. These are packages and there are no subpackages either. All packages are (a tiny technical few aside) equal. Modules group packages to be versioned together.

Comment: Does [Call a package's function without using its package name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954293/call-a-packages-function-without-using-its-package-name) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Volker trying to represent `models.Person{...}`  as `Person{...}` actually makes no sense.

If longer package names is what is concerning you, you can always make use of import aliases as shown in the below code

```
package main
import m "models"

func main(){
     p := m.Person{name: "Karam", age: 5}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to avoid mentioning models.Person{...} and be able to use only Person{...}

No.

(Well, technically that is wrong, but writing models.Person is the **right thing** to do in each an every cases (including yours!) and you should never use a dot-import like `import . "models"`. If you do that everybody will hate you.)