# How can I bring something from a nested module path into the current scope?

Tags: go

In Rust we can bring something from a nested module path into current scope:

```rust
use rand::{Rng, thread_rng};
```

Instead of `rand::thread_rng()`, we can now write `thread_rng()`.

Is there anything equivalent in Go?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a package's function without using its package name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954293/call-a-packages-function-without-using-its-package-name)

Comment: While you *can* import an entire package into your namespace, this is discouraged except in special circumstances. By using qualified names like `fmt.Println` instead of `Println`, tools can find the symbol definition just by looking at the imports. This makes the tools simpler, and I’m sure there are tools which don’t always work if you import a whole package into your namespace. (Just chalk it up to a difference between Rust and Go language design.)

Comment: See: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#import-dot

Comment: *this is discouraged* — it's generally discouraged to call a free function from another module without the module prefix in Rust as well, although bringing types, traits, and macros is generally accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes and no. You can't import just specific symbols, but you can import a whole package into your namespace, using Dot Imports:

```
package main

import (
    . "fmt"
    . "math"
)

func main() {
    Println(Pi)
}
```

This however creates the problem of collisions in symbols. If we try to do the following for example - import packages that have the same symbols:

```
import (
    . "crypto/md5"
    . "crypto/sha1"
)
```

We will get the following error:

```
./prog.go:5:2: BlockSize redeclared during import "crypto/sha1"
    previous declaration during import "crypto/md5"
./prog.go:5:2: New redeclared during import "crypto/sha1"
    previous declaration during import "crypto/md5"
./prog.go:5:2: Size redeclared during import "crypto/sha1"
    previous declaration during import "crypto/md5"
./prog.go:5:2: Sum redeclared during import "crypto/sha1"
    previous declaration during import "crypto/md5"
./prog.go:5:2: imported and not used: "crypto/sha1
```

So in general it's not recommended, especially not in libraries, and should only be used in tests to resolve circular dependencies.